# Problems url pass value

Tags: java, android, caching, webview

I want to create an application that has a Webview that will handle two URLs.

When the first URL loads, the user will be prompted to click a button to be redirected to the second url to fill a capatcha and return true.

The problem is when returning to the first URL, the JavaScript of the page did not receive the return value.

Problem caching?

Comment: some code would help to identify the problem

Comment: I program under Sketchware IDE.
I'm just using a webview with a load URL.